# Shell Script intend to read argument after '|'

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, command-line-arguments

Hi I was wondering how to read the argument after "|" pipe from shell script.

For example, when I run ./tmp.sh ls -la | sort
I could only get 2 arguments, which is "ls" and "-la".

Is there any way to read "| sort" without modifying the command, and realize only with shell script?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: The shell interprets the command line and only passes two arguments to your script.

Comment: It's hard to understand why you want to override a basic functionality of shell scripting. As you keep extending this demand to work outside of the framework, you'd ultimately have to write your own "non-shell". At least include a reasonable use-case for why you think you need this in the body of your question.It's likely there is another solution to your problem that **uses* the shell features, rather than hopes to override them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pass the entire command as a string to your script.

```sh
./tmp.sh -c "ls -la | sort"
```

...or without a flag...

```sh
./tmp.sh "ls -la | sort"
```

Afterward, you can [split the string into an array in your script](https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-split-string/).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could check ps axf, but part of the beauty of pipes is the loose coupling they give, because bash knows what is in your pipeline, not the individual pieces of the pipeline.  This makes writing filters simple.